# NIC driver kills link

Tags: networking, drivers, server

On a clean build of 16.04.02 Server on a Supermicro X9DRI-LN4F+ motherboard, I lose network link during boot when the igb module finds the i350 NIC's (i.e. I have link light up until the module loads).  Once booted, I can get network card working by running:

```
rmmod igs
modprobe igs
ifdown eno1
ifup eno1
```

Hoping to avoid troubleshooting, I ran apt-get update and upgrade but that didn't fix it.

I tested the NIC on CentOS-7 without any problem.

I'm not sure what to try next.

Comment: Seems to work fine on on 16.04.2 Desktop so I am at a complete loss.

Comment: Can you post the output of `dmesg` after a boot, but before you've (manually) recovered the link?